# yeoman generator-angular-cordova errors

Tags: cordova, yeoman-generator

I have a problem installing an angular cordova app with yeoman. (more specifically [this](https://www.npmjs.org/package/generator-angular-cordova) generator.)

Here's what happens:

```
$ yo angular-cordova

     _-----_
    |       |
    |--(o)--|   .--------------------------.
   `---------´  |    Welcome to Yeoman,    |
    ( _´U`_ )   |   ladies and gentlemen!  |
    /___A___\   '__________________________'
     |  ~  |
   __'.___.'__
 ´   `  |° ´ Y `

Out of the box I include Ionic and some AngularJS recommended modules.

[?] What is the name of your app? (Spaces aren't allowed) HelloCordova
[?] What would you like the package to be? io.cordova.hellocordova
[?] What platforms would you like to add support for? Android, iOS
[?] What plugins would you like to include by default? 
[?] Would you like to copy some sample icons for cordova? Yes
Creating cordova app: helloCordova

/usr/lib/node_modules/generator-angular-cordova/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory '/home/leoha/projects/mobile-app-v2/www/js/index.js'
    at Object.fs.unlinkSync (fs.js:760:18)
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/generator-angular-cordova/app/index.js:246:16
    at _rejected (/usr/lib/node_modules/generator-angular-cordova/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:808:24)
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/generator-angular-cordova/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:834:30
    at Promise.when (/usr/lib/node_modules/generator-angular-cordova/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:1079:31)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/usr/lib/node_modules/generator-angular-cordova/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:752:41)
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/generator-angular-cordova/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:821:14
    at flush (/usr/lib/node_modules/generator-angular-cordova/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:108:17)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:419:13)
```

If someone knows how to solve this, I'd be really grateful.

Comment: Make sure you have the folder empty before running `yo angular cordova`

Comment: I did that. variations of this error still persist.
But I figured out the problem. The error was caused by a change in the cordova plugin, causing it not to create the index.js in www/js/ folder and the generator would simply blow up.
I solved it for myself and ran into something different, more specifically the grunt-bower-install package, which I converted to wiredep and made some small changes all over the place.

Comment: I wanted to submit a pull request to the original repo, but didn't do that mainly because even though my setup works, it's not completely bulletproof because it needs some manual changes after the generation. For example, the karma generator (the one from npm) generates always the same karma.conf and for some reason none of the flags work. The latest version, that I cloned and linked locally, works like a charm. I'm wondering if the author should publish the latest version to npm to make everyone happy.

Comment: Hi Trevor. I am getting the same issue as you. Could you explain how you resolved it? Thanks

Comment: simply find the line that blows up and wrap it in an if statement, my error was caused by an unexistent path. Hope that helps

Comment: @TrevorDonahue Yea, what did you change to get it to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I got it and fixed it.**

I just installed the generator (locally and not globally)

```
C:\PhoneGap\Workspace\Demos\cordovayeoman>npm install generator-angular-cordova
```

after the successful installation of the package. When I ran:  "**yo angular-cordova**"  I got the same exception (see snapshot)

[image]

then I created another folder (**MyCordovaApp**) inside "the folder" where I installed/configured the generator plugin i.e.

```
From:   C:\PhoneGap\Workspace\Demos\cordovayeoman\

To:   C:\PhoneGap\Workspace\Demos\cordovayeoman\MyCordovaApp
```

Now here I ran again: "**yo angular-cordova**" and it worked well :)  (see snapshot)

[image]

Note:- I had selected iOS platform that's why it given me excetion while generating stuff for iOS on Windows machine.

and here is the generated stuff.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Ok, here is what I did on MacOS 10.10 (Yosemite) to get this to work, and it's a bit different from others. Note that I do not use `sudo`, but use the approach [John Papa recommends](http://www.johnpapa.net/how-to-use-npm-global-without-sudo-on-osx/).

1. npm -g uninstall generator-angular-cordova
2. mkdir ~/projects/node
3. git clone https://github.com/wangshijun/generator-angular-cordova.git && cd $_
4. npm link
5. mkdir ~/projects/my-new-project && cd $_
6. yo angular-cordova

It ends up asking some questions about dependencies on my machine, but I don't always see them, so the generator appears to hang.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is described (and a solution provided) here: https://github.com/wangshijun/generator-angular-cordova/issues/2